# Выбор паттерна проектирования WCF

Tags: c#, сеть, wcf

Есть следующая задача: Приложение A посылает приложению B данные. Приложение B эти данные получает и уведомляет приложение A, после чего осуществляет необходимые действия с полученными данными.

Какой подход запрос-ответ подойдет лучше всего для решения такой типовой задачи? Важен порядок и синхронизация состояния двух приложений.
Приложение A посылает данные, ожидает сообщения от приложения B, что они были доставлены.В ответ на сообщение о подтверждении посылает подтверждение подтверждения приложению B, которое выполняет операции с данными, одновременно с приложением A.

Вписывается ли такой подход в стандартные паттерны реализации WCF? duplex messaging? Насколько вообще хорош такой подход, может быть есть варианты лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такую штуку Вы вполне можете реализовать при помощи WCF. Вам нужно создать дуплексный WCF-сервис, чтобы организовать двухсторонее общение между приложениями. [Вот](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/building-duplex-wcf-services.html) хорошая статья, там подробно всё описано.